# Listening to events about the creation of new pools

Tags: web3.js

is it possible to use json rpc to track the events of creating new pools or providing liquidity? If yes, can you please provide some minimal example? I've seen several similar telegram bots with notifications and would like to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Helius Webhooks](https://docs.helius.dev/webhooks-and-websockets/quick-start/solana-program-account-webhooks-alpha) if you're looking to subscribe to events from a program (or multiple).

Here's a minimal example from their docs:

```
const createProgramWebhook = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.helius.xyz/v0/webhooks?api-key=<PASTE YOUR API KEY HERE>",
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          webhookURL: "https://your-webhook-server.com/your-endpoint",
          accountAddresses: [],
          accountAddressOwners: ["PASTE YOUR PROGRAM ADDRESS HERE"],
          webhookType: "account",
        }),
      }
    );

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log({ data });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("error", e);
  }
}

createProgramWebhook();
```

This will listen to all account updates for a given program, negating the need to spam getProgramAccounts (a normally heavy RPC call). From this, you'll have to filter your response for the corresponding accounts needed.

They have a helpful blog post that explains it in far more detail here: https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-telegram-bot